# Codeigniter & AJAX: Retrive ID from dynamic loaded content?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have an issue using **AJAX Dynamic loading a content in a div.** I am creating an article page and I am loading only once the navigation header and footer and there is a div besides which loads the content from the rest of the pages. The problem is that **I need to get the ID from the URL** so I can **get the data for each article**, but because I am using this method of loading and in the **URL** is only the **#** to activate the AJAX Request.

Can someone suggest a solution how to retrive the ID, so I can keep using this way of loading cause it's cool ?

Cheers

Comment: can you shows hows ur url look like

Comment: How does a new article is loaded. ? You can fire an event on it and do the ajax to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "data-id" for each one of your article link and set your article ID into it:

```
<a href="#" class="ajax" data-id="120">article link</a>
```

Before making an ajax request by jquery retrieve the the data-id value:

```
$("a.ajax").click({
   var id=$(this).attr( "data-id" );
});
```